# React Native fetch different result with/without wifi

Tags: node.js, rest, reactjs, react-native, fetch-api

I experienced some strange behaviour testing my ReactNative-App on my device. Where you might be able to tell me what i am doing wrong.

Frist of all I have a REST-API returning a list of posts. Here some output requested with postman (it is the same url as later on in the app):

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": "6bb373c6dbe8c4782121068223a1d5bf710a14a62943443bdc5c017ce873935a",
            "description": "",
            "upvotes": 0,
            "downvotes": 0,
            "creationTime": "2017-08-16T04:44:03Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "5ae791aa33512dc179f075649f68731f269c366a37807f7da9eeeabafcda8c7d",
            "description": "",
            "upvotes": 0,
            "downvotes": 0,
            "creationTime": "2017-08-16T04:42:27Z"
        },
    ],
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "servertime": "2017-08-16T07:02:32.250978864+02:00"
}
```

I would expect to obtain this object over wifi **and** mobile internet.

Here the codesnipped for requesting my API inside my app:

```
exports.getPosts = function() {
    return fetch(HTTP.baseurl + "/image", {
        method: "GET"
    }).then(res => res.json()).then((res)=>{
        //this is the line you will see the output from
        console.log(JSON.stringify(res, null, 2));
        return res
    });
}
```

If request the API with wifi I get the same object as in postman.
But if requested with mobile internet I get the following object:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "id": "5ae791aa33512dc179f075649f68731f269c366a37807f7da9eeeabafcda8c7d",
        "description": "",
        "upvotes": 0,
        "downvotes": 0,
        "creationTime": "2017-08-16T06:42:27.37228137+02:00"
    },
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "servertime": "2017-08-16T06:42:27.4874009+02:00"
}
```

Tested on:

```
macOS:        10.12.6
XCode:         8.3.3
iOS:          10.3.3 (iPhone 6)
node:          8.4.0
react:        16.0.0-alpha.12
react-native:  0.45.1
```

EDIT:

I also reproduced it on a fresh react native app only inserting following lines of code:

```
//first send an image to the API
fetch("http://services.impressions-app.com/test/image", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({"blob": blob, "description": ""})
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
        //then request all the images including the new one
        return fetch("http://services.impressions-app.com/test/image", {
            method: "GET"
        })
    }).then(res => res.json()).then(res => {
        //should log an array of imageobjects (see postman response above)
        console.log("LOADED", res);
    }).catch(e => {
        console.error(e)
    });
```

I got an object like above with data as an object instead of an array:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "id": "06c50436c2b2b671a64ce3b57b6cac76b648a83ed621305a0f6a55f8186957ba",
        "description": "",
        "upvotes": 0,
        "downvotes": 0,
        "creationTime": "2017-08-17T08:00:24.198626835+02:00"
    },
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "servertime": "2017-08-17T08:00:26.031231455+02:00"
}
```

Tested on:

```
macOS:        10.12.6
XCode:         8.3.3
iOS:          10.3.3 (iPhone 6)
node:          8.4.0
react:        16.0.0-alpha.12
react-native:  0.45.1
```

EDIT #2:

I watched the log files and it only logged this request when I requested over wifi. The other requests were logged as expected.

Maybe it is a caching problem?

Did anyone of you have a similar problem?

thank you very much

Comment: The two response are not in same structure, in first response `data` property is an array but in the second response `data` is an object. Are you sure that they are coming from same source?

Comment: I don't know the API but, there is a chance that backend dev programmed his app to return an object if there is only one result, and return array otherwise.

Comment: @VahidBoreiri yeah they are definetly from the same source because i did not change anything but the wifi switch.

Comment: @Eden yeah the same came in my mind but the postman request shows what the API should return no matter how much objects there are

Comment: Can you test both network with postman? first use your common wifi and then use your mobile hotspot and call the API by postman again.

Comment: If you're doing this in IOS they only accept https connections. If you want to use a non SSL connection then you have to add the url to the p list

Comment: @VahidBoreiri i tried with the mobile hotspot as you said, but the API seems to act normal...

Comment: @VahidBoreiri But i can repoduce the error on the simulator via mobile hotspot.

Comment: As I understand you run it on the simulator and the api response was different in wifi and mobile data. Do you hvae a local server for API? If you do, make sure when your app is using the wifi it doesn't use the local API server.

Comment: yeah i repoduced it in the simulator. I also have a local version of the API, but the server was not started when I tested that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was the following:

**Short Version:**

It is a caching problem.

If you want to be sure to definitely call the API again, you can add an auto increment to the url.

```
"https://yourapi.com?1"
"https://yourapi.com?2"
"https://yourapi.com?3"
```

**Long Version:**

Before firing the request mentioned above i fired another request, that was a `POST` to the same URL. That post returned an object like this:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "data": {
        "id": "06c50436c2b2b671a64ce3b57b6cac76b648a83ed621305a0f6a55f8186957ba",
        "description": "",
        "upvotes": 0,
        "downvotes": 0,
        "creationTime": "2017-08-17T08:00:24.198626835+02:00"
    },
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "servertime": "2017-08-17T08:00:26.031231455+02:00"
}
```

This object was cached and returned when requesting the original URL via `GET`.

That might be an issue for React Native since I expected to only get cached values for URLs from URLs I called before with the same method.

Like this:

```
POST "https://yourapi.com" => "foo"
GET  "https://yourapi.com" => "bar" (not cached)
GET  "https://yourapi.com" => "bar" (cached)
```

And **NOT** like this:

```
POST "https://yourapi.com" => "foo"
GET  "https://yourapi.com" => "foo" (cached)
GET  "https://yourapi.com" => "foo" (cached)
```